# Angular 2 (7.3.6): Add/load component into named router-outlet with code without changing browser Url

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components, router-outlet

- I have an Angular 2 V 7.3.6 browser application.
- The application is a SPA, but with many components and sub-components.
- In the index.html file, I have a main component, that hosts named
  router outlets and it looks like this:

HTML code for main component

```
<div class="div-A">
    <router-outlet name="Outlet-A"></router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="div-B">
    <router-outlet name="Outlet-B"></router-outlet>
</div>

<div class="div-C">
    <router-outlet name="Outlet-C"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

- Inside the main components TypeScript class, I want to create new
  instances of other components and show them in Outlet-A, Outlet-B or
  Outlet-C.
- Just as an example, I create a LoginComponent in the constructor and want to a show it in Outlet-B

TS code for main component:

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';
import { Router }         from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './LoginComponent';


@Component
(
    {
        selector: 'main',
        templateUrl: './main.html',
        styleUrls:['./main.css']
    }
)
export class MainComponent
{
    constructor (private router :Router)
    {
        login:LoginComponent = new LoginComponent();

        this.CreateAndShowAnyComponent("Outlet-B", login);
    }

    CreateAndShowAnyComponent(outletName:string, component:any): void
    {
        //WHAT TO DO HERE?

        //IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE?

        //PSEUDO CODE:

        this.router.outlets[outletName].clear();
        this.router.outlets[outletName].add(component);
    }
}
```

**What I want to achieve is the following:**

1. No hardcoded, typed routes. Not inside HTML, not inside component/modules.
2. All instance creating and routing should be managed by code.
3. The browser Url must always stay the same and never change (localhost:4200 vs localhost:4200/changedRoute)

**What is different from the other questions/answers on SO?**

I have read many other examples across SO and the internet and all of them still include "hardcoded" route definitions like this: (a code snippet from another thread)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},

];
```

*I don't want hardcoded routes like above...*

**My question is:**

Is this possible and what should the code look like?

(see => PSEUDO-CODE above in the main.ts example)

Comment: Your requirement can be summarised as a need to load particular components strictly through code and show them in a pre-designated area in your html without changing the url. For example `LoginComponent` in the `div-B` router-outlet. In this case you should look at structural directives and alternatives like `ng-template`, `NgComponentOutlet` and so on. Since you are not really utilising any routing features, trying to use `router-outlet` only to display components is retrofitting a feature and will result in unnecessary complexity in your code.

Comment: From a quick overview of https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet, this seems promising. And of course you are right: Why use router-outlet, when I don't need the feature? The thing is: All examples and video tutorials regarding Angular include routing with router-outlet. Since Angular is very new to me, I thought, this would be the way to go....hmmmm...

Comment: what if you try lazy loading without router?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-without-router?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts
or dynamic komponents